# Converting fixed to fluid css issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive website. I am taking the pixel widths and converting them to fluid using target ÷ context = result. Everything fits perfectly in the 1140 wrapper when fixed but when I convert everything to fluid it doesn't fill up the entire 1140px width wrapper. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

You can see how everything is lining up here and how its overall width of the 3 columns is more narrow on the fluid:[image]

[HTML page for fixed width](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/index-fixed.htm)

[CSS for fixed](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/css/main-fixed.css)

[HTML page for fluid](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/index-fluid.htm)

[CSS for fluid](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/css/main-fluid.css)

Shouldn't they all be the exact same width?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you incorrectly calculating percentage for columns `margin` and `width`.

Since you use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) on `section#hp-cols`, the inner width for the section with `10px` padding in both side is **`1120px`**, *not* **`1140px`**. If you use `width: 31.57894%;` (`360px` divided by `1140px`) for your column, it would give you columns with **`353px` wide** *instead of* **`360px`** (since `31.57894%` of `1120px` is `353px`).

The solution is to recalculate all percentage value, and use 1120 as divider. It should be like this.

```
section#hp-cols {
    padding: 0 .89285714%; /* 10px / 1120px */
}
section#hp-cols ul li {
    width: 32.1428571%; /* 360px / 1120px */
}
section#hp-cols ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 1.78571429%; /* 20px / 1120px */
}
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/7Aq74/) and [**full demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cuplizian/7Aq74/show/light/) of fluid width page. I also made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/J8EJ6/) and [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cuplizian/J8EJ6/show/light/) of fixed width page for comparison.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That's it - thank you! I totally forgot about the border-box!

Answer (score 0):

You have padding on your fluid example. Really though, the way you are doing the wrapper is "wrong" (not as accurate/efficient). It should be

```
#wrapper {
width:1140px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

Then your contents inside can be floated with a percentage width and through media queries, you change the width of the wrapper at breakpoints.

Why not use a framework like Bootstrap? It would make this much easier/quicker.

Comment: Why not use a framework like Bootstrap? ** In some ways yes it might be easier but I'm doing it myself Because I want to learn this and build from scratch if possible.

by having a set width on the wrapper, isn't this then becoming a fixed width? I don't want to set breaking points on the wrapper, I want it to be completely fluid.

The reason I have a top margin on the wrapper is because the header is fixed.

Comment: You were using exact numbers for fluid in your question.